# how can i set ID of qty in nativescript

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, native

I have button + - and i want to save the result of that butotn + -. But i have no idea id of the button/qty. First, variable in run debug android is empty. And when i insert qty:1, the result is "variables: {qty_used: 1}". Here is the code

```
data() {
        return {
            pageData: this.tempData,
            list: {},
            is_checked_all: false,
            is_saving: false,
            is_completed: false,
            qty: 1
        }
    },
```

and here is the method

```
methods: {
      toggleSelectAll() {
            if (this.is_completed) return
            this.is_checked_all = true
      },
      save(qty) {
            if (this.is_saving) return
            this.is_saving = true
            var vm = this

            this.$apollo.query({
                query: gqlUseVoucher,
                variables: {
                    id: this.pageData.id,
                    qty_used: qty
                },
                fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
            }).then((resp) => {
                if (resp.room.AuthorizeVoucherUsingID) {
                    vm.is_saving = false
                    vm.$modal.close()
                    vm.$store.commit('setSuccess', 'Voucher breakfast berhasil divalidasi')
                } else {
                    vm.is_saving = false
                    errorHandler(vm, null, 'Voucher breakfast tidak dapat digunakan')
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                vm.is_saving = false
                console.log(error)
                errorHandler(vm, error)
            })

        },
```

now, what should i do to get the ID of that button/qty. Am new in nativescript xoxo. thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. But if you want to know which object was clicked, use the event argument, `event.object` will tell you which element triggered the event.

Comment: solved. thank you:)